# Variable automatic assignment and incrementation

Tags: python, class, variables, variable-assignment

I am creating a small program that receives 2 text files. Each file has information about an object or a person. Each object has always 8 items and each person has always 7 items. I managed to have this information automatically placed in lists, regardless of the number of objects or people that text files may display. I therefore obtained two main lists. Let's call it 'D' and 'C'.
Each list has several lists with the respective information of the object or person.

Example:

```
D = [[att1, att2, att3, att4, att5, att6, att7, att8], [object 2], ..., [n-object]]

c = [[att1, att2, att3, att4, att5, att6, att7], [person 2], ..., [n-person]]
```

As I am working with objects, I created two different classes, one to handle each list. The constructor method receives the attributes of each person or object.

Example:

```
class DDD(object):
     def __init__(self, att1, att2, att3, att4, att5, att6, att7, att8):
          self._att1 = att1
          self._att2 = att2
          etc etc etc etc
```

The same goes for the other class.

This is where I'm having problems. How do I automate the creation of instances for each object?
The difficulty lies in the allocation of variables. You could certainly create a 'for loop', taking into account 'len (D)' or 'len (C)' to create the instances. I could call the arguments of the constructor method by index.

like:

```
for i in D:
     X1 = classD(i[0], i[1], i[2], etc etc)
     ......
```

How do I automatically make variable (X2, X3, X4, Xn) incrementation to make the assignment?

Comment: Why not make your constructor take a list of attributes?

Answer (score 0):

Please format your code when asking questions.

Would it suit you to create objects and put them in a list?

Try something like this:

```
class DDD(object): 
    def init(self, att1, att2, att3, att4, att5, att6, att7, att8): 
        self._att1 = att1
        self._att2 = att2
        ...

people = []
for person in D:
    x = DDD(person[0], person[1], ...)
    people.append(x)
```

This way you will end up with a list of DDD objects based on data from D.

If that is what you want the above code is better written as:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Person:
    attr1: int
    attr2: str
    ...

people = [Person(*person) for person in D]
```

I'm taking advantage of list comprehensions and dataclasses to write it out nicer.